# Find the location on a slide of selected bullets

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a vba that can position shapes over bullets (because the stock bullets are too boring). I'm having trouble determining the location of each bullet so that I can position the shape on top of it.

The vertical position would be more valuable, as those are more difficult to line up. The bullets are constantly moving (spread out to fill shape), but I don't have a problem manually rerunning the macro each time the move.

Any advice on getting an output similar to .Bullet.Left or .Bullet.Top, similar to what can be done with a shape?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overlaying an object and then having to deal with auto formatting of the text frame, could you export your custom bullet shape to the file system as a PNG picture using .Export and then reimport it as a bullet using .Type and .Picture like this:

```
' ================================================================================
' PowerPoint VBA Macro
' Auther : Jamie GArroch of YOUpresent Ltd. http://youpresent.co.uk/
' Purpose : exports any on-slide object e.g.shape, group etc. and then
'           imports it for use as a bullet
' References : None
' Requirements : User must select two obects on the slide, one of which must
'                contain the text to be bulleted
' Inputs : None
' Outputs : None
' ================================================================================
Sub ExportShapeAndLoadAsBullet()
  Dim oShpText As Shape
  Const TmpPath = "C:\Temp\" ' make sure this path exists or changeto one that does
  Const BulletName = "myBullet.png"

  On Error GoTo errorhandler
  With ActiveWindow.Selection
    ' Check the user's selection
    If .Type <> ppSelectionShapes Then
      MsgBox "Please select the shape to use as a bullet and the text box to apply it to.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Incorrect Selection"
      Exit Sub
    End If
    If .ShapeRange.Count <> 2 Then
      MsgBox "Please select the shape to use as a bullet and the text box to apply it to.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Incorrect Selection"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Export the object to use as a bullet and set a reference to the object to apply the bullet to
    If .ShapeRange(1).HasTextFrame Then
      If .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame.HasText Then
        Set oShpText = .ShapeRange(1)
        .ShapeRange(2).Export TmpPath & BulletName, ppShapeFormatPNG
      End If
    End If

    If .ShapeRange(2).HasTextFrame Then
      If .ShapeRange(2).TextFrame.HasText Then
        Set oShpText = .ShapeRange(2)
        .ShapeRange(1).Export TmpPath & BulletName, ppShapeFormatPNG
      End If
    End If
  End With

  If oShpText Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Couldn't find any text in either shape.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "No Text Found"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Apply the exported bullet to the text
  With oShpText.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet
    .Type = ppBulletPicture
    .Picture TmpPath & BulletName
    .RelativeSize = 1
    Kill TmpPath & BulletName
  End With

  ' Clean up
  Set oShpText = Nothing
Exit Sub
errorhandler:
  MsgBox Err & " : ", Err.Description
End Sub
```

This will save having to code positioning and you can also set the relative scale of the bullet picture.